# How do I set the Gain of a logitech Webcam Pro 9000 in C#?

Tags: c#, webcam, logitech

I'm developing an application that uses a Logitech Webcam Pro 9000 (and no other) to capture and filter a stream. I've used AForge.net and gotten a quick start. I've already managed to get the webcam stream and apply a filter to each individual image.

However I want to use the webcam in specific environments. To help the user, I want to create controls in the application that allow the user to change the webcam's gain and exposure time (I know the last one appears to be more tricky than the first).

I've been looking into DirectShow.Net, but I don't grasp that quite yet. Is this a feasable solution? If yes, are there good examples/tutorials?

The final goal (regardless of libraries):
**How can I make a control that changes the gain (and exposure) on the Logitech Webcam Pro 9000 and turn of any automatic adjustments?**

Comment: I think the hardware has to support what you're doing, and most webcams don't let you adjust something as technical as exposure time. Did you try increasing the brightness/contrast of the resulting images instead? That might be a lot easier.

Comment: It is a lot easier, except that I want to analyze the frames after capturing them and I have a conversion table that is calibrated to particular (gain and exposure) settings. To make the application more generic (i.e. support different tables) I want to add the controls described in my question.

Comment: I had a similar issue, check this post: [C# set webcam properties][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949828/set-webcam-properties-e-g-gain-brightness-exposure

Comment: Funny, I stumbled upon that question myself today, it worked out nicely for gain and the other parameters, so thanks. However, this doesn't work for exposure.

Answer (score 1):

Setting exposure works fine with DiredtShow.Net, but there is one catch!

You will have to set the exposure only AFTER you started the capturing graph. For some reason, it doesn't work other way.

Comment: Do you have any (links to) examples/tutorials? Thank!