# set webcam properties (e.g. gain, brightness, exposure)

Tags: c#, video, directshow, webcam

I'm writing a small application on C# (Winforms) where I am accessing a Webcam to capture some images.

Does anyone know if it's possible to access and set the webcam's properties like gain, brightness and exposure using c#? (Don't pop-up Webcam's own Properties window)

I've tried using the DirectShow library and it only allows me to set the exposure but no the gain nor brightness.

Cheers in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set them using `IAMVideoProcAmp::Set` method, the settable properties include:

```
typedef enum tagVideoProcAmpProperty {
  VideoProcAmp_Brightness,
  VideoProcAmp_Contrast,
  VideoProcAmp_Hue,
  VideoProcAmp_Saturation,
  VideoProcAmp_Sharpness,
  VideoProcAmp_Gamma,
  VideoProcAmp_ColorEnable,
  VideoProcAmp_WhiteBalance,
  VideoProcAmp_BacklightCompensation,
  VideoProcAmp_Gain 
} VideoProcAmpProperty;
```

The camera driver certainly needs to support/implement the properties in order for them to be adjustable.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! I'll give it a try right now and I'll get back to you. Cheers!